# Unity doesnt move object by eulerangles

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

Script open doors, unity call that function but i dont see any errors and any effect aswell.
Any Ideas where is a problem? I tried with Delta.time instead of dividing elapsed and finishedtime.

```
public class OpenDoor : MonoBehaviour
{

    private float DoorOpenAngle = 90.0f;
    public bool open = false;


    private Vector3 defaultRot;
    private Vector3 openRot;
    float ElapsedTime;
    float FinishTime;

    void Start()
    {
        defaultRot = transform.eulerAngles;
        openRot = new Vector3(defaultRot.x, defaultRot.y - DoorOpenAngle, defaultRot.z);

        float ElapsedTime=0f;
        float FinishTime=1.5f;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (open)
        {
            ElapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(defaultRot, openRot, ElapsedTime / FinishTime);


        }

    }
    public void Unlockdoors()
    {

        open = true;



    }
}
```

Comment: try using gameObject.transform not just transform...

Comment: Nope its not that

Comment: any chance your door is already at 90 degrees?

Comment: Don't use Update to animate doors. Use coroutines or animation for that.

Comment: @BugFinder  `transform` and `gameObject.transform` return both exactly the same reference but second requires one more reference access ;)

Comment: @derHugo I always thought that but I've seen it where transform seems to get a component reference not the game object, hence ,I've often had to write gameobject to make it move.. I've never nailed down exactly why..

Comment: @BugFinder no makes no difference .. if you need a `GameObject` reference then yes ofcourse you'll use `gameObject` but for the `Transform` reference you only need `transform` ;)

Comment: hmm weird, I know you know your stuff @derHugo but only the other day running through some code someone had on a tutorial it didn't work till I put gameoject on the transform... as I said it seems a bit random one day I will track it down

Comment: You need to set `open = true`. Try adding `Unlockdoors();` to the end of `Start`. If that doesn't work, I'm guessing you have another script setting the door's rotation and the changes by this one are getting overwritten.